# Typescript infer parent type based on nested member

Tags: typescript

Typescript can infer the type of a value based on questions you ask it at if statements. For example, one member of an object can be inferred based on another:

```js
type ChildType = 'a' | 'b';

type Child<T extends ChildType> = T extends 'a' ? { type: 'a', color: 'blue' } : T extends 'b' ? { type: 'b', color: 'red' } : never;

interface Parent<T extends Child<ChildType>> {
    child: T extends Child<infer R> ? Child<R> : never;
}


function test<T extends Parent<Child<any>>>(parent: T) {
    if (parent.child.type === 'a') {
        parent.child.color === 'red'; // complains because should be blue
    }
}
```

However, performing the same check using nested members of a type, it doesn't seem to provide the same effect.

```js
type ChildType = 'a' | 'b';

interface BaseParent<T extends Child<ChildType>> {
    child: T;
}

interface Child<T extends ChildType> {
    type: T;
}

type Parent<T extends ChildType>
    = T extends 'a' ? { color: 'blue' } & BaseParent<Child<'a'>>
    : T extends 'b' ? { color: 'red', opacity: 2 } & BaseParent<Child<'b'>>
    : never;

function test<T extends Parent<ChildType>>(parent: T) {
    if (parent.child.type === 'a') {
        parent.color === 'red' // should complain, but doesn't
    }
}
```

This could easily be rectified using type guards, however I'm searching for a way to do this without them.

Answer (score 0):

First things first - having parent data dependency on it's child is propably not proper architecture. Dependencies should go down. You can think about it in the first place.

But if you want, I'd do it something like (I've added animal example to make it easier for me to understand):

```
type AcceptedAnimal = 'dogs' | 'cats';

interface ParentBase {
  accepts: AcceptedAnimal
}

interface Cat {
  meows: boolean;
}

interface Dog {
  race: string;
}

type Parent = DogOwner | CatOwner;

interface DogOwner extends ParentBase {
  animal: Dog
}

interface CatOwner extends ParentBase {
  animal: Cat;
}

function isDogOwner(parent: ParentBase): parent is DogOwner {
  return parent.accepts === 'dogs';
} 

function test(parent: Parent) {
  if (isDogOwner(parent)) {
    parent.animal.race; // ok
    return;
  }

  parent.animal.meows; // ok;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I appreciate the comment about what I understood as raising the "type" to the top level. Unfortunately I'm restricted by the current model and that simply isn't an option. It seems like what I'm trying to do is simply impossible without using type guard functions! Thanks.